# Ubuntu resumes immediately after suspending

Tags: 16.04, display, suspend, power-management, hibernate

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64 bit. When I press the 'Suspend' button, it goes to suspend but immediately resumes again without me pressing any other device. And what's worse is that when it resumes, the monitor remains in sleep and pressing keyboard buttons does not seem to have any effect and the only way I seem to be able to start working is by pressing the physical restart button on the system box (which of course forcefully restarts the PC). How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is the `Suspend` button on your PC case or your keyboard? What are the make and model? Have you tried to suspend via the menu? Any difference?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I tried suspending via the menu. I am using a Desktop and I cannot see a hardware suspend button neither on the PC case nor the keyboard.

Comment: You meant a "software button on the screen" I read it as a "hardware button". My mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Suspend does not turn off your computer.It puts the computer and all peripherals on a low power consumption mode.Hibernate saves the state of your computer to the hard disk and completely powers off. When resuming, the saved state is restored to RAM.
For suspending you can just close your Lid ,that way it wont restart !

you can also try this
Go to /etc/defaults/grub, change value of
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"

Then run:
sudo update-grub

Comment: I am using a Desktop, so there is no lid. What does `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"` actually do? Can you please explain before I actually try that?

Comment: Suggestion does not work, for me sleeps dim the screen, pc slows down, then immediately starts up again with the lock screen, wake up on periferals has been disabled.